# How to Combine Multiple CSV Files Using Python for Your Analysis

Tags: python, csv, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate my csv files into one file.

I try to use  Pandas

```py
csv_files = ['data_SHTest1_283.csv', 'data_SHTest1_284.csv']
# Read and concatenate the CSV files into a single DataFrame
combined_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in csv_files], ignore_index=True)
# Save the combined DataFrame to a new CSV file
combined_df.to_csv('Master File VS.csv', index=False)
```

But I am encountring errors, such as:

```
  chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "parsers.pyx", line 904, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "parsers.pyx", line 879, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._check_tokenize_status
  File "parsers.pyx", line 2058, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2602, saw 2
```

Comment: Check your line 2602  if there's no inconsistent delimiters.

Comment: I would start by reading each file into a dataframe separately to determine which file is throwing the error. Basically pandas `read_csv()` is choking on one of these two files at that particular line number.

Comment: the columns of the CSV files should match each other. and the data should be consistent.